# Having trouble with animating: hiding and showing multiple objects under a parent

Tags: blender

(Blender 2.8) In blender, I'm trying to animate this svg made up of 100+ parts that has a parent to theoretically connect them all because that is what someone would expect the parent function to do.

However, when I insert a frame on the option to hide the object under object - visibility - show in viewports/show in render it only hides the one part of the svg that is parent of the rest.

Does anyone know how I can somehow hide all of the objects under a parent object all at once at the same time by inserting a frame? If this isn't possible is there any way to actually group multiple objects together and for it to allow me to insert a frame that hides all of it?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to combine them into one object so that you only have one to animate, select them and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

The easiest way to animate the visibility of multiple objects is with a script. Paste this into blenders [text editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/text_editor.html) and adjust to show and hide on the desired frames.

```
import bpy

def hide_children(obj, fr, hide):
    obj.hide_render = hide
    obj.keyframe_insert('hide_render', frame=fr)
    obj.hide_viewport = hide
    obj.keyframe_insert('hide_viewport', frame=fr)
    for c in obj.children:
        hide_children(c, fr, hide)

parent = bpy.data.objects['Curve']
hide_children(parent, 1, True)
hide_children(parent, 10, False)
```

When run, it will keyframe all the children of the "Curve" object to be visible and hidden.

Comment: So all I have to change is                                                                                        `parent = bpy.data.objects['Curve']`  to                                                                    `parent = bpy.data.objects['whatevermyobjectiscalledd']`?

Comment: also how would I tell it to hide on a specific frame? I'm not so good a coding sorry.

Comment: @theSpeciamOne, yes to setting the parent. The last two lines are examples, the `1,True` is hiding the objects on frame one, the `10,False` will unhide them on frame 10. Repeat these lines for each frame you want to show or hide the objects.